# Display data from single table where column values match

Tags: database, join, match, self

I have a table called 'Artists' which has columns Artist_ID, Artist_Name, Artist_Genre
and have been trying to figure out how to list the Artists where they share the same Genre.

I think I might need a self join but can't quite get there. Can you please help?

```
Desired Output
Artist Artist 2 Shared Genre 
A      B        Classic 
B      C        Pop
```

Comment: What type of database (RDBMS)?

Comment: What if there is another artist, so three share a genre? Do you want an Artist 3 column in the output? Or are you really better off with something like genre + a csv list of Artists Classic | A,B,D Pop | B,C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server this would do what you ask, but I don't think it is really what you are asking.

```
CREATE TABLE Artists(Artist_ID INT, Artist_Name VARCHAR(100), Artist_Genre VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO Artists VALUES
(1,'A','Classic')
,(2,'B','Classic')
,(2,'B','Pop')
,(3,'C','Pop')

SELECT a.Artist_Name [Artist 1]
      ,b.Artist_Name [Artist 2]
      ,a.Artist_Genre [Shared Genre]          
  FROM Artists a
       INNER JOIN
       Artists b ON a.Artist_Genre = b.Artist_Genre
 WHERE a.Artist_ID < b.Artist_ID
```

EDIT:  I think it is worth showing you here as well that you can group by and generate a artist list. In sql server the syntax is a mess, but it get the job done.

```
SELECT b.Artist_Genre,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(Artist_Name AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                FROM Artists a
               WHERE a.Artist_Genre = b.Artist_Genre
               ORDER BY Artist_Name
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') Artist_List
  FROM Artists b
 GROUP BY b.Artist_Genre
```

Comment: Thanks Karl, Yes that is sufficient and yes RDBMS. Although as you mentioned it would be ideal to have all artists on the same line where genre matched.
Would I just have to specify c.Artist_Name [Artist 3] and keep going if I wanted more or is there a more precise way to have all Artists on the same line?

Comment: You *could* add add more self joins to get them on the same line, but that doesn't scale well at all. Instead you could produce a Genre and a Artist List field with, for example, group_concat in MySQL. That primarily why I asked about what type RDBMS, but I meant which one, i.e. sql server, mysql, access, etc.

Comment: Sorry, SQL server. Ohk Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @user3517854 I added a way to do group+conact in SQL Server. Since the original is sufficient you should probably go ahead and mark the answer as accepted.